# JavaFX Issue with Switching Scene

Tags: java, javafx, static

I have a `Utility` class in which I am trying to create a `static` method called `switchScene` to be able to easily switch scenes in my stage. This is the code I tried to use:

```
public class Utility {
    public static void switchScene(String path) {
        Stage stage = getMainStage(); // Assume this returns the primary stage
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(path));

        try {
            Parent root = loader.load();
            Controller controller = loader.getController();
            controller.start();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I thought this code would work (I'm making every controller for my view implement the `Controller` interface which just has a `start` method on it.), however I get this error message:

```
java: non-static method getClass() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Is there something I can do to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get path as a `String`. Change it to `URL`

```
public class Utility {
        public static void switchScene(URL path) {
            Stage stage = getMainStage(); // Assume this returns the primary stage
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(path);

            try {
                Parent root = loader.load();
                Controller controller = loader.getController();
                controller.start();
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                stage.setScene(scene);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now every one can call it with their own fxml wherever it may be and the signature is less confusing about what the argument is supposed to be:

```
Utility.switchScene(SomeClass.class.getResource("someView.fxml"));
```

It's irrelevant to your question but I also suggest that you get the `Stage` as an argument or via dependency injection rather than calling a function ([Inversion of Control principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)) and throw `IOException` rather than catching it, as it informs users of utility class about possible ways things can go wrong. I also think it's not a bad idea to return the `Controller` rather than returning `void` so that it can be used by users.

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for the tips on using good practices!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call `getClass()` inside `static` methods, you need to use it along with the class name, so you need to change your code as shown below:

```
loader.setLocation(Utility.class.getClass().getResource(path));
```

Comment: Hmm, that definitely makes the error go away but it doesn't seem to like that, it says `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.` Is this a case where I can't abstract this code into this separate `Utility` class?